# Put value on table inside variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to put a filename that is already listed into a table. I need to put the filename to address to access the file.

I already tried this:

```
DECLARE @filename AS varchar(255)
DECLARE @filepath AS varchar (255)
--SELECT MAX(id) FROM ##TempFileName

SET @filename = 'SELECT tfn.subdirectory FROM ##TempFileName tfn WHERE id = ''1'''
EXEC (@filename)
--PRINT @filename 

set @filepath = 'D:\romli\LockAmount_out\' + @filename  + '.txt'
EXEC (@filepath)
PRINT @filepath
```

I expect `@filepath` will contain something like this `D:\romli\LockAmount_out\123456.txt`, how I can store the filename in a table to store in a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that you want two different variables : @filename and @filepath, you can assign them on the same query.

```
select @filename = tfn.subdirectory,
       @filepath = 'D:\romli\LockAmount_out\' + tfn.subdirectory + '.txt'
from ##TempFileName tfn 
where tfn.id = '1'
```

Answer (score 2):

why do you need to use Dynamic SQL to get `@filename` ?

You can simply query it directly

```
SELECT @filename = tfn.subdirectory 
FROM   ##TempFileName tfn 
WHERE  tfn.id = '1'
```

or if you want to concatenate with the path and file extension

```
SELECT @filepath = 'D:\romli\LockAmount_out\' + tfn.subdirectory + '.txt'
FROM   ##TempFileName tfn 
WHERE  tfn.id = '1'
```

Comment: so the result of the query will look like something like 123456.txt, so i can put the result to address like this 'D:\romli\LockAmount_out\' + @filename, any suggestion so i can put the result without using dinamic sql?

Comment: how to combine 'D:\romli\LockAmount_out\' with the result of query?

Comment: just use the `+`. Updated the answer